# Is it possible to achieve this zoom & pan effect on a direct image and not a div with a background-image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found [**this**](http://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz) codepen showcasing a zoom and pan effect for images. As far as I can tell, the code works by assigning a background-image to each div based on its `data-image` attribute. Is there any way that I can do this on a direct `img` tag instead of a div with a background-image?

EDIT: This is the kind of mark-up I'm talking about. **A container div with an actual img tag inside of it.**

Comment: So do you want to simply add the effect mentioned to an existing `<img>` tag, or create the markup via JavaScript based on `data` attributes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygddoj) now.

Think i got it to look kinda like you want it

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div data-scale="1.1" class="product-single__photos tile" id="ProductPhoto">       
        <img class="photo" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1698/6183/products/bluza_dama_39377a_large.jpg?v=1487178925" alt="Last Skirt" id="ProductPhotoImg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup. I'm not even going to finish my answer after this. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the margin to adjust the image position

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  margin:0%;
  transition:0.5s;
}
img:hover{
  width:120%;
  margin:-10;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/06/13/58/arlberg-pass-833326_960_720.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: The linked example also reacts to mouse movement inside the div by offsetting the image.

Comment: If you know the basics of javascript and jquery you can just replace the offset that is changed by the mouse movement through the margin. I just wanted to give you an idea of how it works

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It would involve giving the elements some CSS:

```
div.product-single__photos {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.product-single__photos > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

And have the Javascript manipulate the `<img>`'s `width`, `height`, `top` and `left` properties.